# Outlook on premise Add-in : get reccurence item info

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm in the midst of developping an add-in to book appointments
I was trying to implement a functionnality that allows for user to set the recurrence through the add-in.
I am using Outlook on premise and am capped to the Mailbox API 1.5 and am getting this error when trying to getAsync() the recurrence item :

`result: Object { value: undefined, status: "failed", error: {…} } ​​ error: Object { name: "Une erreur relative à l'hôte s'est produite", message: "Operation is not supported.", code: 5000 } ​​ status: "failed" ​​ value: undefined`

Is there a way to still access this data through the add-in and to set it or should I drop this functionnality and let the user set the recurrence without the add-in ?

Answer (score 0):

Recurrence support was added in Mailbox requirement set 1.7 per [Outlook add-in API requirement set 1.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/requirement-set-1.7/outlook-requirement-set-1.7?view=common-js-preview) and [Get and set recurrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-and-set-recurrence). It should work for users whose combination of client and platform version supports requirement set 1.7.

You could set the minimum requirement version to 1.7 in the VersionOverrides element of the manifest, so that supported users could use the recurrence functionality via the add-in, and users who don't support this set will not have the add-in appear in their Outlook client. See [Specify Office applications and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements) and [Outlook add-in manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manifests) for further guidance.